# Getting list of friends on FAN Page, not personal page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the js sdk to get a list of my friends with no problem.
The list I get is from my facebook personal page (Tony Easterbird)

I alse have a fan type page, called Katahdin Sheep.
I want to get a list of people who like this page. (Katahdin Sheep).

the appID is the same for both pages, so I am a little confused on how to get the list.

If have tried:

```
   FB.api('me/KatahdinSheep', function(response){... etc
```

and also:

```
   FB.api ('Katahdin.Sheep', function(response){ ... etc
```

Can you please steer me in the right direction?  Your help is truly appreciated.

Tony

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can retrieve a list of users by a `page_id` (using the API).
I believe the only thing you can do is test a specific `user_id` against a `page_id` to see if **that** user has already liked your page.

Through the Facebook website, you can see exactly who has liked your page but I believe Facebook has limited the API in this way to prevent data mining by applications.